# Redirect old domain all links to new domain

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have a old website in Wordpress and new one will be in Wordpress as well. 
For example there is site www.xyz.com now I want to create new site on new domain www.abc.com
and also wants all the links on my old site to be redirect to the new site. I know how can we redirect the whole domain but what I wants is that if someone goes to this link www.xyz.com/blog he should be redirected to www.abc.com/blog . If I redirect the whole domain it will redirect every page to www.abc.com instead of sending them to relevant page. How can make the redirect to the relevant pages.

Answer (score 1):

U should find .httacess file on old site and edit the redirect to the new one, or u could find a plugin on wordpress to do it for you.

Comment: You mean I should use 301 redirect plugin on the old site and redirect all the pages to relevant new pages? for example www.xyz.com/blog to www.abc.com/blog and www.xyz.com/about to www.abc.com/about . If yes then in future if I don't keep the old domain and host what will happen then?

Comment: Yes u got it. Also you could be a bit witty about it and add a redirect page with php which shows if someone redirected from previous to new one saying he will be redirected to new page and show the new page index.html on www.newsite.wordpress.com. As per the domain and host... I think they delete the accounts that have not been used in a long time

Comment: Also here is a good reference to the .httacess file https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-